# What determines my post-raid health status after not escaping Tarkov?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

After unsuccessful raids, Therapist will not always ask for the usual 10k RUB to fix me up.

Upon closer inspection, this is not just the status effects - the *health point pool* itself appears to alternate between different settings. What exactly decides whether I re-enter the world of the living with or without health points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different outcomes, the remaining variation is the automatic heal that already starts happening while in the post game screen:

1. **30% health points**
2. **1% health points**

Usually the first outcome is selected, unless the death happened under any of the following circumstances:

1. disconnected
2. from self-inflicted damage (grenades, ricochets)
3. without a firearm equipped
4. by the hand of someone from the same lobby (team kill)
5. by the hand of someone who has since extracted

This appears to be an intentional measure of discouraging certain behaviour.

The following status effects remain after raid and Therapist will offer to take care of these, for a price:

- fracture, toxin, bleeding

The following status effects are always cleared:

- blacked out limb
- ability buff & de-buff
- stun, flash, fatigue, contusion, tunnel vision
- pain, tremor (cleared, but will be re-applied if *fracture* is not healed)

Comment: May be worth noting if you don't heal everything then tremor/pain (as examples) can come back upon reentering a raid - some players do this intentionally to go for quest kills such as 'while having a tremor'